# Add GPS Coordinates to iPhone Contact

Tags: ios, maps, contacts.app

I like to hike (with dogs).  Please how can I add GPS coordinates to an iPhone contact address field or otherwise like "the lodge near Au Sable Falls, NY" at 44.181430, -73.965213.  There is no road within 2 miles.
I can add it into the Notes field but minor pain to copy/paste each time I need the information.

Comment: So far no correct answers; the methods above add an address but not a GPS location.  That's not helpful when hiking off-road.  Anybody actually know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe we're answering the wrong question, what would be the purpose of having the GPS coordinates added to the contact?

Comment: Having GPS in contact is the easiest way to find them later.  I suppose I could copy and paste them into an app like OneNote or EverNote if I am anal about documenting with keywords, but that's painful both at the time of save, AND when finding later.  Too much copy and paste, and no SIMPLE, quick way to search for, especially when out of range.  As mentioned, i'm pretty sure I was able to do this some time ago.

Comment: But are this places or persons? For places I use other apps, like Garmin's Basecamp, Motion-X GPS For instance, that have some tracking / waypoint capabilities that may be of use.

Answer (score 3):

I would create new contact named "the lodge near Au Sable Falls" or your choice.

Then in the home address enter the coordinate 44.181430, 73.965213

It will now allow you to show it on the map.

[image: location]

[image: location]

Comment: No,when i select/touch the GPS coordinate in the contact (getting it there works fine), nothing happens. I had thought that was working some time ago, but it hasn't worked for some time, at least since iOS 8.3, maybe before.  Obviously I should go 8.4 but am hesitant because it's iPhone 5, and already a bit sluggish, and poor on battery, and I don't want to use Apple Music (yet), AND I lost all my many KB shortcuts with 8.3.  Thanks.  (the coordinates are wrong cause I haven't been there lately, just wanted to make the question interesting--it IS one of the nicest places on Earth :) )

Comment: did you pay attention how to enter the coordinates numbers ?

Comment: I tested entering GPS three ways ways; 1. Add from maps, 2. copy and paste from whatsmygps.com, or similar Safari site, and 3. copy and paste from compass app.  If I have to actually type them manually that's too kludge and defeats the purpose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your GPS coordinates to the right format, you can use URL’s like the ones below in your contacts (as homepage URL’s) and click them right from the contact and navigate in either Apple Maps or Google Maps.

Examples (note that the %20 in the middle of the coordinates is an encoded space):

[http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=42°59'25.0"N%2082°25'02.8"W](http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=42%C2%B059'25.0%22N%2082%C2%B025'02.8%22W)

[http://maps.google.com/?daddr=42°59'25.0"N%2082°25'02.8"W](http://maps.google.com/?daddr=42%C2%B059'25.0%22N%2082%C2%B025'02.8%22W)

NOTE:  The above work from an iOS device.  On other platforms, YMMV.

Pro Tip:  You can use https://maps.google.com to enter GPS coordinates in almost any format and it will convert them to the above form, for copy/paste into the URL.  Just remember to use %20 in place of the space.

Comment: Note that a `+` works just as well as `%20`.

Comment: For Apple Maps, the `35.131481, -115.435625` format also works. This format is available in the Apple Maps `Copy Coordinates` pin actions. No space needed.

Answer (score 2):

I added your coordinates Apple Maps, I don't know if the place is correct,

[image: pin at coordinates on Apple Maps]

anyway, after finding the correct location on the map, tap and hold if there is no pin to drop one, and then tap on the pin to show options.

[image: dropped pin options]

You can create a new contact or add to an existing one from there.

Comment: So far no correct answers; the methods above add an address but not a GPS location.  That's not helpful when hiking off-road.  Anybody actually know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Drop a pin to the location. Then do the following:

1. Tap Share icon.
2. Choose Mail. Then a mail draft will open.
3. Send the mail to yourself.
4. Open the received mail in iPhone. The mail will have "Dropped Pin.loc.vcf" attached.
5. Tap "Dropped Pin.loc.vcf". Then Contacts App will be launched.

Then you have the map URL. (The coordinate is embedded in the URL as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ABGPS app : http://roudgersoft.com/en/app/abgps/

ABGPS

• adds your GPS location to your Contacts cards.

• opens your favorite navigation app directly from the device address book.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a workaround, by adding a URL to a contact. In the URL you type http://www.google.com/maps/place/(coordinates), for
example:

http://www.google.com/maps/place/29.927639,31.078943

Now when you open the contact and click on that URL it'll open the location in Google Maps.